# Visual Studio 2010 background flickering

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8

I'm working on VS2010 and Windows 8.
whenever I run the application windows starts flickering which is quite weird.

I tried following things but didn't get any help out of it.

1. Open Tools/Options dialog
2. In the options tree select the Environment/General page.
3. Uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" then uncheck "Enable rich client visual experience" checkboxes.
4. Close the Tools/Options dialog

and I also tried making some changes in regedit.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe video card drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Set `DoubleBuffered` to `True` and see if it helps.
Also, try different settings in the `BackgroundImageLayout`, if you have an image for the background.